# Is the series $\frac{1}{p_n}$ ,where $p_n$ is $n^{th}$ prime number, convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I assumed $p_n=nlogn$ and evaluated the convergence using cauchy's condensation test and got the series divergent. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120592, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15946

Comment: The intuition that $p_n$ behave somewhat similar to $n \log n$ indeed hints that the prime harmonic series $\sum_{n\geq1} 1/p_n$ will diverge, but this is by no means a proof.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! This clarifies a lot of things! But can my proof be stated incorrect?